# Can I stack 3 CNN2D layer with LSTM, Error in input to LSTM layer

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning

I am trying different neural entwork architecture. One of this is composed of convolutional 2D layer stacked with LSTM layer, but i am getting error

```
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Flatten, Dense, LSTM, Reshape,TimeDistributed

X = np.array([[(1,2,3,3,1),(3,2,1,3,2),(3,2,2,3,3),(2,2,1,1,2),(2,1,1,1,1)],
              [(4,5,6,4,4),(5,6,4,3,2),(5,5,6,1,3),(3,3,3,2,2),(2,3,3,2,1)],
              [(7,8,9,4,7),(7,7,6,7,8),(5,8,7,8,8),(6,7,6,7,8),(5,7,6,6,6)],
              [(7,8,9,8,6),(6,6,7,8,6),(8,7,8,8,8),(8,6,7,8,7),(8,6,7,8,8)],
              [(4,5,6,5,5),(5,5,5,6,4),(6,5,5,5,6),(4,4,3,3,3),(5,5,4,4,5)],
              [(4,5,6,5,5),(5,5,5,6,4),(6,5,5,5,6),(4,4,3,3,3),(5,5,4,4,5)],
              [(1,2,3,3,1),(3,2,1,3,2),(3,2,2,3,3),(2,2,1,1,2),(2,1,1,1,1)]])
y = np.array([0, 1, 2, 2, 1,1,0])

#X = X.reshape(X.shape[0], X.shape[1], X.shape[2], 1)
#print(X)


model = Sequential([
    Conv2D(32, (2, 2), activation='relu', input_shape=(5, 5, 1)),
    LSTM(64, return_sequences=True),  # LSTM layer with return sequences
    Flatten(),
    Dense(64, activation='relu'),
    Dense(3, activation='softmax')  # 3 output classes
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(X, y, epochs=10)
```

I tryied ro reshape the Conv2d output but i am not able to solve the issue.
Can anyone show me how to reshape the output?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to add a new dimension to your X array, because you set the input shape to be (5, 5, 1) and your current X shape is (7, 5, 5, 1) where last dimension is the number of channels:

```
X = np.expand_dims(X, axis=-1)
```

Now given your logic, I assumed that you want to reshape the output of Conv2D (width, height, features) to LSTM input (time_points, features) by merging the width and height into one dimension by multiply them. So the output shape will reshaped to (width * height, features) where after applying the Conv2D the array shape will be changed from (5, 5, 1) to (4, 4, 32), and then to fit LSTM you reshape to (16, 32):

```
model = Sequential([
    Conv2D(32, (2, 2), activation='relu', input_shape=(5, 5, 1)),
    Reshape(target_shape=(16, 32)),
    LSTM(64, return_sequences=True),  # LSTM layer with return sequences
    Flatten(),
    Dense(64, activation='relu'),
    Dense(3, activation='softmax')  # 3 output classes
])
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(X, y, epochs=10)
model.summary()


Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d (Conv2D)              (None, 4, 4, 32)          160       
_________________________________________________________________
reshape (Reshape)            (None, 16, 32)            0         
_________________________________________________________________
lstm (LSTM)                  (None, 16, 64)            24832     
_________________________________________________________________
flatten (Flatten)            (None, 1024)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                (None, 64)                65600     
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 3)                 195       
=================================================================
Total params: 90,787
Trainable params: 90,787
Non-trainable params: 0
```